# asset images not precompiled in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, precompile

I was developing this rails app that has mostly static pages. I downloaded a template from bootstrapicious and created a pages controller to hold all my static pages, changed the file names to have a .html.erb extension and the routes. Everything was working out fine in the index page; all images, css and js were working fine. But other pages aren't loading the animate js and images. I created a link of the home pages without using root_path and it behaved the same. I'm stranded and don't know what to do. Please help.  quite a newbie in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Rails server and try this command

```
rake assets:precompile
```

After this re-start your rails server!! Let me know if this what you wanted.

Comment: I did that and I see them precompiled in the terminal but still nothing.